# mkdir -p and touch for creating a range of subdirectories and files -- How does it work?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-expansion

I found these commands in a tutorial that create a parent directory with hundreds of sub-directories, followed by a touch command that creates hundreds 26 empty files in created sub-directories:

```
mkdir -p playground/dir-{00{1..9},0{10..99},100}

touch playground/dir-{00{1..9},0{10..99},100}/file-{A..Z}
```

My question is how does this syntax work exactly? What is the bracket expansion doing and what does the `00` and `0` and `100` signify? I know that `100` is the last value but I'm not sure how the `00` and `,0` work. Same question for the touch command as well.

Please help me understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's have a look:

1) command `mkdir -p playground/dir-{00{1..9},0{10..99},100}`

You simply create 100 directories in `playground/`, each of them in the following format: `dir-xxx` where `xxx` are digits. By `{00{1..9},0{10..99},100}`, you're saying 3 things:

1. create directories `00x` where `x` is from 1 to 9 that's the `00{1..9}`
   part of it
2. create directories `0xx` where `xx` are from 10 to 99, that's
   the `0{10..99}`
3. part of it create directory 100

2) when you have all the directories from 1), then you run the `touch` command

You simply touch files in the following format `file-x` where `x` is one character from the range A-Z. By that `{00{1..9},0{10..99},100}` part, you're simply saying, you want to touch the files in those directories created in 1). As you can see, the part in braces is the same as in the `mkdir` command.

Hope it helps.
If you want to explore a bit more about brace expansion, you can read for example this: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

Comment: A "simple" version would probably use `{001..100}` to generate the numbers from `001` to `100`, but that's a different story...

Comment: @Freddy perhaps the origins of the OP's code pre-date bash 4.0-alpha (which apparently introduced *`{0x..0y}` (zeropadding brace expansion)* - see for example [BashChanges: Quoting, expansions, substitutions and related](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges#quoting_expansions_substitutions_and_related)

Comment: @steeldriver Yeah, could be. FYI, this [book](https://books.google.de/books?id=OCFKdl3wEDIC&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq=touch+playground/dir-%7B00%7B1..9%7D,0%7B10..99%7D,100%7D/file-%7BA..Z%7D&source=bl&ots=kTI-uPwCre&sig=ACfU3U0DYtUu2x99mc3Jc45MzkURInR-bQ&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=touch%20playground%2Fdir-%7B00%7B1..9%7D%2C0%7B10..99%7D%2C100%7D%2Ffile-%7BA..Z%7D&f=false) seems to be the source of the code.

Answer (score 0):

See "Brace expansion" in the bash man page.

> Supplied integers may be prefixed with ‘0’ to force each term to have the same width.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html